# git diff branch_a branch_b return true or false

Tags: bash, git, bitbucket, git-bash, bitbucket-pipelines

I am fairly new to bash scripting and I am trying to build a script to compare branches in 2 different repos in bitbucket.

currently, I have this code:

```
if [[ clone -eq 0 ]]; then 
    cd ${1}
    echo "
    ********************************
    CLONE SUCCESSFUL. 
    ADDING $BB_COMPARE AS REMOTE REPO...
    ********************************
    "
    add_remote=$(git remote add -f b $BB_COMPARE)

    echo "
    ************************************
            UPDATING REMOTE
    ************************************
    "
    git remote update
    echo "
    ************************************
    CHECKING DIFFERENCE
    ************************************
    "
    git_diff=$(git diff master remotes/b/master)
    fi
    if [[ git_diff -eq 0 ]]; then 
    echo "
    ************************************
    ERROR: $1 AND $compare are NOT in sync. 
    ************************************
    "
```

I think git diff is what I am looking for, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I normally do this counting lines.... even with status, because you don't know how big it would be:

```
lines=$( git diff --name-only master remotes/b/master | wc -l )
if [ $lines -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "There are differences"
fi
```

Comment: Why not [`git diff -q`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---quiet)?